# Eventviewer eventid for lock and unlock

Tags: windows, event-viewer

What is the event id in Event Viewer for lock, unlock for a computer in Windows XP, Windows 7, [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista) and [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event IDs to look for in pre-Vista Windows are [528](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=528), [538](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=538), and [680](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=680). 528 usually stands for successful unlock of workstation.

The codes for newer Windows versions differ, see below answers for more infos.

Comment: TL;DR - just to clarify Pre-Vista Windows event [538](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=538) "is not dependably logged". 528/538 in pre-VIsta Windows is not an exact method to determine lock/unlock. Post-vista windows you use new events 4800/4801.

Answer (score 103):

The lock event ID is 4800, and the unlock is 4801. You can find them in the Security logs. You probably have to [activate their auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772704%28v=ws.10%29) using *Local Security Policy* (secpol.msc, *Local Security Settings* in Windows XP) -> *Local Policies* -> *Audit Policy*. For Windows 10 see the picture below.

Look in *[Description of security events in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977519)* under *Subcategory: Other Logon/Logoff Events*.

[image: Other Logon/Logoff Events in Windows 10]

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I was looking for and was much easier to capture and analyze than the other kind of `audit logon events` policy output. Found my settings for Windows 7's Local Security Policy 'tool' Under `Security Settings->Advanced Audit Policy Configuration->System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object->Logon/Logoff->Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events` which captured locking and unlocking the workstation on a domain.

Answer (score 45):

You will need to enable logging of these events. Do so by opening the group policy editor:

> run -> gpedit.msc

and configuring the following category:

> *Computer Configuration* ->
>   *Windows Settings* ->
>   *Security Settings* ->
>   *Advanced Audit Policy Configuration* ->
>   *System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object* ->
>   *Logon/Logoff* ->
>   *Audit Other Login/Logoff Events*

(In the *Explain* tab it says "... allows you to audit ... Locking and unlocking a workstation".)

Comment: "Advanced Audit Policy Configuration" does not seem to be available in Windows XP.

Comment: Peter, you're correct, Advanced Audit Policy Configuration is not available for XP.  It's also true for versions of Windows 2008 R2 and Win7 that do not support joining a domain.  Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692792(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Excellent answer. I guess you can find this same menu here as well as the Local Security Policy editor but I like how you can get there by `gpedit.msc`. Handy tip!

Comment: thanks! thats exactly what I was looking for. Just to complement, audit events will be 4800 for lock event and 4801 for unlock event (at least in windows 10)

Answer (score 29):

For newer versions of Windows (including but not limited to both Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016), the event IDs are:

- 4800 - The workstation was locked.
- 4801 - The workstation was unlocked.

Locking and unlocking a workstation also involve the following logon and logoff events:

- 4624 - An account was successfully logged on.
- 4634 - An account was logged off.
- 4648 - A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

When using a Terminal Services session, locking and unlocking may also involve the following events if the session is disconnected, and event 4778 may replace event 4801:

- 4779 - A session was disconnected from a Window Station.
- 4778 - A session was reconnected to a Window Station.

Events 4800 and 4801 are not audited by default, and must be enabled using either Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) or Local Security Policy (`secpol.msc`).

The path for the policy using Local Group Policy Editor is:

- Local Computer Policy
- Computer Configuration
- Windows Settings
- Security Settings
- Advanced Audit Policy Configuration
- System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object
- Logon/Logoff
- Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events

The path for the policy using Local Security Policy is the following subset of the path for Local Group Policy Editor:

- Security Settings
- Advanced Audit Policy Configuration
- System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object
- Logon/Logoff
- Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events

Comment: "4648 - A logon was attempted using explicit credentials" was the magic event id I needed, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no such a thing as Lock/Unlock. What you have to do is:

1. Click on "Filter Current Log..."
2. Select the XML tab and click on "Edit query manually"
3. Enter the below query:

   ```
   <QueryList>
     <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
       <Select Path="Security">
       *[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType']='7']
        and
        (System[(EventID='4634')] or System[(EventID='4624')])
        ]</Select>
     </Query>
   </QueryList>
   ```

That's it

Answer (score 4):

To identify unlock screen I believe that you can use ID 4624. But then you also need to look at the Logon Type which in this case is 7: http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4624

Event ID for Logoff is 4634

Answer (score 4):

Security Settings -> Advanced Audit Policy -> System Audit -> Logon/Logoff -> Audit Other Logon/Off Events -> On Success

Enables the following:

```
4800 - workstation locked
4801 - workstation unlocked
4802 - screensaver invoke
4803 - screensaver dismissed
```

Windows 10 professional

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 the event ID for lock=4800 and unlock=4801.

As it says in the answer provided by Mario and User 00000, you will need to enable logging of lock and unlock events by using their method described above by running gpedit.msc and navigating to the branch they indicated:

> Computer Configuration -> 
>   Windows Settings -> 
>   Security Settings ->
>   Advanced Audit Policy Configuration -> 
>   System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object -> 
>   Logon/Logoff -> 
>   Audit Other Login/Logoff

Enable for both success and failure events.

After enabling logging of those events you can filter for Event ID 4800 and 4801 directly.

This method works for Windows 10 as I just used it to filter my security logs after locking and unlocking my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows 10 Home edition.  I was unable to get my event viewer to capture events 4800 and 4801, even after installing the Windows Group Policy Editor, enabling auditing on all the relevant events, and restarting the computer.  However, I was able to discover other events that are tied to locking and unlocking that you can use as accurate and reliable indicators of when the PC was locked.  See configurations below - the first is for PC Locked (the event connected to displaying C:\Windows\System32\LogonUI.exe) - and the second is for PC Unlocked (the event for successful logon).

[image]

[image]