# Is there any possible way to track the windows lock and unlock time using vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to track the time for windows lock and unlock.
Is there any possible way to track the windows lock and unlock time using vba excel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh? Please clarify what you are asking. Which windows? Which lock time?

Comment: Thanks, for ur reply. I am using windows 7. I want to track the system(windows 7) lock(windows+L) and unlock time.

Comment: I still don't get it. When does this time start? And when does it end? Why do you think Excel is the tool for measuring times?

Comment: OP is referring to the user locking & unlocking the screen/desktop.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Declare Function SwitchDesktop Lib "user32" (ByVal hDesktop As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenDesktop Lib "user32" Alias "OpenDesktopA" (ByVal lpszDesktop As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal fInherit As Long, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseDesktop Lib "user32" (ByVal hDesktop As Long) As Long
Private Const DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP As Long = &H100


Function Check_If_Locked() As String
    Dim p_lngHwnd As Long
    Dim p_lngRtn As Long
    Dim p_lngErr As Long
    p_lngHwnd = OpenDesktop(lpszDesktop:="Default", dwFlags:=0, fInherit:=False, dwDesiredAccess:=DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP)
    If p_lngHwnd = 0 Then
        system = "Error"
    Else
        p_lngRtn = SwitchDesktop(hDesktop:=p_lngHwnd)
        p_lngErr = Err.LastDllError

        If p_lngRtn = 0 Then
            If p_lngErr = 0 Then
                system = "Locked"
            Else
                system = "Error"
            End If
        Else
            system = "Unlocked"
        End If
        p_lngHwnd = CloseDesktop(p_lngHwnd)
    End If
    Check_If_Locked = system
End Function

Private Sub Form_Timer()
Debug.Print Check_If_Locked
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off to look in the event log afterwards rather than trying to use Excel to track in realtime when this happens. See [this answer for the event log id values.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11385241/4243498)

There is also [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/528884/in-windows-7-how-to-query-times-when-the-computer-was-locked) on SuperUser.